# Creating Calendar

Tags: sql-server, calendar, reporting-services

I have created a SSRS report to show holidays that have been booked at a company, on each line it shows date from and date to, is there a way of getting the data to add a line for each day rather than a single line with from and to? as I want to populate a calendar using these fields.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question...there are few missing pieces make it hard to read..actually to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is regularly solved using a "calendar" table, i.e. a table that has a list of all dates. Then your query looks something like this:

```
select c.date
from data_table d 
        inner join
     calendar_table c 
        on c.date between d.start_date and d.end_date
```

There's an example of how to create a very powerful calendar table [here](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/).